# How to Set Custom Validator on FormControl Angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular7

How to Set Custom Validation Angular as i am getting undefined of controls

```
FormControl.setValidators(this.validateCall);

    validateCall(): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null => { // not getting control value here
            const val = control.value;
            if(val == null || val == undefined) {
                return {
                    atLeastOneRequired: {
                        valid: false
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: who is upvoting this? I mean the question is incomplete in terms of explanation!

Comment: where is `index` btw?

Comment: Please post the complete/relevant code to reproduce an issue

Comment: i have done changes please look

Comment: If possible then create a stackblitz (which is possible in this case), will help

Comment: i am unable to get control value while setting custom validators

Comment: `FormControl.setValidators(this.validateCall);` - huh? You need to call `setValidators` on an instance of `FormControl` - i. e. on some specific existing form control - not on _class_.

Comment: i did it here for common understanding actually i am using this on formControl not on the class

Comment: @user2822322 check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pa9S8_3Rs8A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom validator seems incorrect. You should remove

```ts
 return (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
```

Also no need for the nested object in the error. So modify your validator to:

```ts
validateCall(ctrl: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  const val = ctrl.value;
  if (!val || val === '') {
    return {
      atLeastOneRequired: true
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

The way you are setting the validator to the formcontrol is correct, since according to your comment *i did it here for common understanding actually I am using this on formControl not on the class*. In some cases you might also need to manually call `updateValueAndValidity` on the form control after setting the custom validator.

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-ywpkjk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Reactive forms validation. [form-validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

```
this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
'name': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(4),
  forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
]),
'alterEgo': new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo),
'power': new FormControl(this.hero.power, Validators.required)
});
```

Comment: But i want to set forbiddenNameValidator when certain condition pass not at the starting.

Comment: I have made a stackBlitz example: [Reactive forms custom validation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kznln) . 
Try to typing bobby first and last name